# Concatenate array with existing array in document

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of `stages` in my `MentorProfile` document and I want to concatenate `lessonsWithComments` array with `stages`. Is this even possible without having to loop through the `lessonsWithComments` and then querying for each iteration with `updateMany`

```
MentorProfile.updateMany(
                {},
                {
                    $push: {
                        stages: {
                            lessonsWithComments
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).then((update) => res.json(update));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you.

```
MentorProfile.updateMany(
   {},
   { $push: { stages: { $each: lessonsWithComments } } }
).then((update) => res.json(update));
```

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!